# Spring - how to use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to dynamically load files

Tags: java, spring, properties

i have the next properties files with Spring Framework

config.properties
with content

```
environment=devel //posible values: devel, testing, prod
```

and with the previous environment property, choose some of the following files to load dynamically

```
config-service1-devel.properties
config-service1-testing.properties
config-service1-prod.properties
config-serviceN-devel.properties
config-serviceN-testing.properties
config-serviceN-prod.properties
```

and then, with spring i want load the properties, i'm solve to load the first properties file but i dont understand how to use expression language to complete the values of the dependent properties.

```
<bean id="MainApplicationProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location"
        value="file://#{systemProperties['jboss.server.home.dir']}/conf/services.properties" />

    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="$mainProperty{" />
    <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}" />
</bean>
<bean id="SecondApplicationProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    depends-on="MainApplicationProperties">

    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>file://#{systemProperties['jboss.server.home.dir']}/conf/serviceOne/service1-$mainProperty{environment}.properties</value>
            <value>file://#{systemProperties['jboss.server.home.dir']}/conf/serviceTwo/service2-$mainProperty{environment}.properties</value>
            <value>file://#{systemProperties['jboss.server.home.dir']}/conf/serviceN/serviceN-$mainProperty{environment}.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>
```

the error output is the next,

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /..../conf/serviceOne/service1-$mainProperty{environment}.properties (No such file or directory)
```

my opinion is, the value has not replaced

helpme, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when `BeanFactoryPostProcessors` are starting to be invoked, they are already instantiated. So even thou the first `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` modifies the bean definition of the second `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, it has no effect as both beans have been already instantiated.

Comment: the 'locations' property of 'PropertyPlaceHolder', has not passing evaluating process by the expression language to retrieve the real value of location, the question is, why the EL not process the value of 'locations' property?

Comment: I've reproduced the behavior and updated my answer... what you are trying to do is not possible.